# Which version of Django REST Framework is affected by IP Spoofing?

Tags: python, django, security, django-rest-framework

REF: https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/ip-spoofing-bug-leaves-django-rest-applications-open-to-ddos-password-cracking-attacks
Reported Date: Jan 11 2022

- Other than providing captcha, what security measure should be taken?
- Which version of Django and/or Python is affected by IP Spoofing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research into the link you shared, Django's source and Django REST Framework's source.

Bare-bones Django is not vulnerable to this, since it doesn't uses `X-Forwarded-For`, and neither is Python.

Virtually all versions of Django REST Framework are vulnerable, since this commit 9 years ago added the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` check: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d18d32669ac47178f26409f149160dc2c0c5359c/rest_framework/throttling.py#L155

For measures you can take to avoid this, since a patch is not yet available, you could implement your own ratelimitter, and replace `get_ident` to only use `REMOTE_ADDR`.

If your Djando REST Framework application is behind a proxy, you might not be vulnerable to this.